# How to create a plot from emmeans function and add p-value significance?

Tags: r, boxplot, emmeans

I ran this code to get *p*-value significance.

```r
em2023 <- emmeans(model1, pairwise ~ Nutrient, adjust = "BH")
pairs(em2023)
```

I have attached a picture of the output.

How do I make a boxplot of the significant p-values from the output?
[image: output]

I have not found code that works but I am new to R so I am probably not looking in the right place.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Be sure to provide [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)